# Do complex numbers have infinitely-many $n$-th roots?

Tags: complex-numbers

The formula for the $n$-th root of a complex number $r(\cos\delta+i\sin\delta)$ is:

$$r^{1/n}\left(\cos\frac{\delta+2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\delta+2k\pi}{n}\right)$$

where $k$ is an integer. Does this imply that complex numbers have infinitely-many $n$-th roots?

Comment: Each complex number $z$ has exactly $n$ $n$-th roots.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to formats your posts.  You'll get a lot more help if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: ok ill try. but its really confusing for me, do you really have to type all the symbols such as $$ and / in order to format, or will something like word's equation function appear?? Thanks for the editing for me btw!

Comment: Now because $r^{1/n}\left(\cos\frac{\delta+2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\delta+2k\pi}{n}\right)= r^{1/n}\left(\cos(\frac{\delta+2k\pi}{n} + 2\pi) +i\sin(\frac{\delta+2k\pi}{n}+2\pi)\right)$  so there are only $n$ distinct *different* values.

Comment: @Shuo Mathjax is a bit of a nuisance until you get used to it. But asking us to help you without helping us do so is a nuisance for us and we might not bother trying.

Comment: @T.Bongers Except for $z = 0$.

Comment: sure ill learn it when i got the time. currently bombed by tests :(

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are periodic functions. The way the n-th root is defined, while you can choose any integer value of $k$ to calculate the root you will find that if two values of $k$ differ by $n$, then they will result in the same root.

For example, the square roots of 1 are:

$\begin{eqnarray}
(1+0i)^\frac{1}{2} & = & (1\mbox{ cis }0)^\frac{1}{2} \\
& = & (1)^\frac{1}{2} (\cos(0 + \pi k) + i\sin(0 + \pi k)\\
& = & \cos(\pi k) + i \sin(\pi k) \\
& = & \cos(0) + i \sin(0), \cos(\pi) + i \sin(\pi), \cos(2\pi) + i \sin(2\pi), \ldots \\
& = & 1 + 0i, -1 + 0i, 1 + 0i, -1 + 0i, \ldots \\
& = & 1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots
\end{eqnarray}$

in other words, $1^\frac{1}{2} = \pm 1$, which we already knew. But it's the same for any number and any integral root - whenever $n | (k' - k)$, the $k'$th and $k$th $n$th roots will be the same value.

However, it does mean that you can have infinitely many distinct roots if $n$ is an irrational number, but that's a more complicated topic where you start having to pick what the "primary" root is.

Comment: Wow thanks. Yea i forgot about the periodicity. But if that's the case, what makes irrational numbers different?

Comment: "But if that's the case, what makes irrational numbers different? "  Different than what?

Comment: different than rational numbers where they have infinite repeating roots, but why aren't irational number's roots repeating even though sin and cos are periodic

Comment: Because the period of cis is 2pi (i.e. cis(x + 2pi) = cis(x)), so you only get the periodicity when (2pi k / n) is a multiple of 2pi, i.e. k / n is an integer. Since k is always an integer, then if n is irrational you will never get k / n integer.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that if $k = j*n + r$ where $r$ is the remainder of dividing $k$ by $n$ then $\sin (\frac {d + 2k\pi}n) = \sin (\frac {dn + 2r}n + 2j\pi) = \sin (\frac {dn + 2r}n$.

Same thing for $\cos  (\frac {d + 2k\pi}n)$

So you only have as many solutions as possible remainders.  And the remainders can be from $0$ to $n-1$.  So there are $n$ solutions and it is finite.  It's just that the values repeat after that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$ r^{1/n}\left(\cos\frac{\delta+2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\delta+2k\pi}{n}\right)$$ is periodic and it will only generate n solutions.

For example if you evaluate it at $k=0$ you get $$ r^{1/n}\left(\cos\frac{\delta}{n}+i\sin\frac{\delta}{n}\right)$$ Now if you evaluate it at k=n, you get $$ r^{1/n}\left(\cos\frac{\delta+2n\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\delta+2n\pi}{n}\right)$$

$$=r^{1/n}\left(\cos(\frac{\delta}{n}+2\pi)+i\sin (\frac{\delta}{n}+2\pi) \right)$$

$$=  r^{1/n}\left(\cos\frac{\delta}{n}+i\sin\frac{\delta}{n}\right)$$